# How to copy a slide to a word Document without using interop?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a task that I have to take go through each slide and input it to a docx file and my condition is that I will not use `interop` or I can use `openXML`.

currently i am trying to take image of each slide and insert those images to a document. I got sampleCode from [here](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource73-Export-PowerPoint-slides-to-Images-with-a-free-NET-library-in-C.aspx) (with help of spire dll) which produce images of each slide.but the problem is that while creating images the DLL put a watermark at the top of the image (Water Mark Text : Evaluation warning : the docume......) is there any other option to take image of a slide or directly input a slide to  a doc file.
and one more thing I can't purchase other license

Answer (score 0):

First: Just pay for the license. The watermark is there for a reason.

To answer your question, an Open XML document is in fact a ZIP file, so it would be quite easy to extract embedded files from there, and even edit them. You just have to extract the file as a ZIP, do your task on them, and zip it again.

You don't need additional libraries to do this, but some may make the zip processing a little easier. If you don't want to use external libraries, you need to use the classes provided under [`System.IO.Compression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thnks for reply. I am aware of licensing. I mention the link to inform that spire can take images of individual slides. and I am trying exactly to do the same thing but till now i failing to do so

Answer (score -1):

You can use OpenXML to add image in document, first you need to convert slide to an individual images and then put them one by one
after searching I got following code snippet to insert image in word document

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using Wp = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using Pic = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;

namespace GeneratedCode
{
    public class GeneratedClass
    {
        // Creates an Body instance and adds its children.
        public Body GenerateBody()
        {
            Body body1 = new Body();

        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphAddition = "00970886", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164292" };

        Run run1 = new Run();

        RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
        NoProof noProof1 = new NoProof();

        runProperties1.Append(noProof1);

        Drawing drawing1 = new Drawing();

        Wp.Inline inline1 = new Wp.Inline(){ DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U };
        Wp.Extent extent1 = new Wp.Extent(){ Cx = 2009775L, Cy = 2276475L };
        Wp.EffectExtent effectExtent1 = new Wp.EffectExtent(){ LeftEdge = 19050L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 9525L, BottomEdge = 0L };
        Wp.DocProperties docProperties1 = new Wp.DocProperties(){ Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Picture 0", Description = "Authentication.jpg" };

        Wp.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1 = new Wp.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties();

        A.GraphicFrameLocks graphicFrameLocks1 = new A.GraphicFrameLocks(){ NoChangeAspect = true };
        graphicFrameLocks1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

        nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1.Append(graphicFrameLocks1);

        A.Graphic graphic1 = new A.Graphic();
        graphic1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

        A.GraphicData graphicData1 = new A.GraphicData(){ Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" };

        Pic.Picture picture1 = new Pic.Picture();
        picture1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("pic", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture");

        Pic.NonVisualPictureProperties nonVisualPictureProperties1 = new Pic.NonVisualPictureProperties();
        Pic.NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualDrawingProperties1 = new Pic.NonVisualDrawingProperties(){ Id = (UInt32Value)0U, Name = "Authentication.jpg" };
        Pic.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties1 = new Pic.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();

        nonVisualPictureProperties1.Append(nonVisualDrawingProperties1);
        nonVisualPictureProperties1.Append(nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties1);

        Pic.BlipFill blipFill1 = new Pic.BlipFill();
        A.Blip blip1 = new A.Blip(){ Embed = "rId6" };

        A.Stretch stretch1 = new A.Stretch();
        A.FillRectangle fillRectangle1 = new A.FillRectangle();

        stretch1.Append(fillRectangle1);

        blipFill1.Append(blip1);
        blipFill1.Append(stretch1);

        Pic.ShapeProperties shapeProperties1 = new Pic.ShapeProperties();

        A.Transform2D transform2D1 = new A.Transform2D();
        A.Offset offset1 = new A.Offset(){ X = 0L, Y = 0L };
        A.Extents extents1 = new A.Extents(){ Cx = 2009775L, Cy = 2276475L };

        transform2D1.Append(offset1);
        transform2D1.Append(extents1);

        A.PresetGeometry presetGeometry1 = new A.PresetGeometry(){ Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle };
        A.AdjustValueList adjustValueList1 = new A.AdjustValueList();

        presetGeometry1.Append(adjustValueList1);

        shapeProperties1.Append(transform2D1);
        shapeProperties1.Append(presetGeometry1);

        picture1.Append(nonVisualPictureProperties1);
        picture1.Append(blipFill1);
        picture1.Append(shapeProperties1);

        graphicData1.Append(picture1);

        graphic1.Append(graphicData1);

        inline1.Append(extent1);
        inline1.Append(effectExtent1);
        inline1.Append(docProperties1);
        inline1.Append(nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1);
        inline1.Append(graphic1);

        drawing1.Append(inline1);

        run1.Append(runProperties1);
        run1.Append(drawing1);

        paragraph1.Append(run1);

        SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties(){ RsidR = "00970886" };
        HeaderReference headerReference1 = new HeaderReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Even, Id = "rId7" };
        HeaderReference headerReference2 = new HeaderReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = "rId8" };
        FooterReference footerReference1 = new FooterReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Even, Id = "rId9" };
        FooterReference footerReference2 = new FooterReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = "rId10" };
        HeaderReference headerReference3 = new HeaderReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.First, Id = "rId11" };
        FooterReference footerReference3 = new FooterReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.First, Id = "rId12" };
        PageSize pageSize1 = new PageSize(){ Width = (UInt32Value)12240U, Height = (UInt32Value)15840U };
        PageMargin pageMargin1 = new PageMargin(){ Top = 1440, Right = (UInt32Value)1440U, Bottom = 1440, Left = (UInt32Value)1440U, Header = (UInt32Value)720U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
        Columns columns1 = new Columns(){ Space = "720" };
        DocGrid docGrid1 = new DocGrid(){ LinePitch = 360 };

        sectionProperties1.Append(headerReference1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(headerReference2);
        sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference2);
        sectionProperties1.Append(headerReference3);
        sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference3);
        sectionProperties1.Append(pageSize1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(pageMargin1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(columns1);
        sectionProperties1.Append(docGrid1);

        body1.Append(paragraph1);
        body1.Append(sectionProperties1);
        return body1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My concern to convert slide to image. I have the code how to insert image to a word document